# Are "meet the needs" and "meet to the needs" both correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> In order to further increase their market share, they must **meet to** the needs of Chinese consumers.
>
> In order to further increase their market share, they must **meet** the needs of Chinese consumers.

I'm more used to the latter, but is it also okay and grammatically correct to use as in the first sentence, *meet to* the demands/needs?

And do they mean the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is correct. I have not heard anyone use "meet to" in the context of the first sentence. But I think you need a 'the' in front of 'Chinese consumers'

**Meet to** could be used like this:

> In order to further increase their market share, they must meet (the Chinese community leaders) to (discuss/better understand) the needs of the Chinese consumers.

Comment: Without further context, the article isn't required. In fact, it would be wrong to add the article in certain contexts. (If it's a general statement, *the* would be out of place.) Without a specific context, the addition of the article looks wrong.